# A simple blank screen is showing up on Nexus 6 Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I am using Nexus 6 API. It is simply showing blank screen and nothing is coming up. I tried all the available devices in emulator but none is working, all it is showing is just a blank black screen. I choosed Hardware GLES 2.0 and Automatic in 'Graphics' of 'Emulated Performance'. I even enabled device frame and disabled it(tried all probablities) but still same response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW6YI.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL3D8.jpg)

I also tried Software GLES 2.0 but it then also the same. Please help me out.

Comment: Turn on intel Virtualization or intel VT in your bios. its need for Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing softwares graphics.
It happens because of intelHaxmEmulator.
Turn on Intel Haxm from you BIOS settings.